# what the argument in the anonymous function represent in a named function?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

Erm, I tried my best to explain what my problem is, sorry for by bad English.
In the below code:

```
    function createCompareFunction(propertyName){

    return function(object1, object2){
       var value1 = object1[propertyName];
       var value2 = object2[propertyName];

       if(value1 < value2){
          return -1;
       }else if(value1 > value2){
          return 1;
       }else{
          return 0;
       }

    };


}

var person = [{name: "Nicholas", age: 29}, {name: "Alex", age: 34}];
person.sort(createCompareFunction("name"));
alert(person[0].name);
```

as you can see in this scope:

```
 return function(object1, object2){
   var value1 = object1[propertyName];
   var value2 = object2[propertyName];
```

there's object1 and object2 arguments
but, when i  call the function, i didnt defined the arguments, but why it automatically knows that it is the object in the array.

Hope you know what i'm talking. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the specification for sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). It tells you what arguments it passes when it calls the function you pass to it (which are the two items in the array that it is currently sorting).